# The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i get Error: The argument type 'Function?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'.

```
  late bool _isFrontImageSelected;
  late bool _isSideImageSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isFrontImageSelected = false;
    _isSideImageSelected = false;
  }

  Future openCamera(String type) async {
    if (type == 'FRONT') {
      frontImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    } else {
      sideImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    }
    setState(() {
      if (frontImage != null) {
        _isFrontImageSelected = true;
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print('front image selected.');
      }
      if (sideImage != null) {
        _isSideImageSelected = true;
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print('side image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Error Function.

```
onPressed: _isFrontImageSelected
                            ? null
                            : () {
                                openCamera("FRONT");
                              }
```

please help me.

[error opencamera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq0W6.png)

Comment: The onPressed attribute, is from a Button or a Custom Widget ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't assign a `null` here.

```
onPressed: _isFrontImageSelected
                            ? null
                            : () {
                                openCamera("FRONT");
                              }
```

Change the `null` to empty function, Like this

```
onPressed: _isFrontImageSelected
                            ? (){}
                            : () {
                                openCamera("FRONT");
                              }
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. now the error has been successfully recovered

Comment: You are welcome dear.  